# how to split this coordinates chart except first number and store(x,y) into two dimensional arrays

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array, split

[as the title,i want to split the coordinate chart as following](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YEYDx.png)

after spliting, it should be like 88 72
                                  47 40
                                  13 67....
and store x and y value into array
how to modify .split(""),if use

> .split(""tab"")

it completely split the string without ignoring the first numbers
,and how to store those numbers into two dimensional array

```
package coordinates;
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*; //scanner and reader
public class Path {
public static void readfromtxt() throws Exception{
    FileReader File = new FileReader("coordinations.txt");
    BufferedReader Reader= new BufferedReader(File);
    String text="";
    String textsub="";//to isolate first line
    String line=Reader.readLine();
        textsub=text+line+"\n";
        while(line!=null){//if there are lines
            text=text+line+"\n";//pass data of line into text
            line=Reader.readLine();//load data of line
            String[]textArrays=line.split(" ");//split by tab 1.1 2.88 3.72
            for(String textArray:textArrays){
                int coordinates=Integer.parseInt(textArray);// to int 
                System.out.println(coordinates);}}
```

Comment: What is not working? Have you read about [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: In the last three lines, just do not iterate over the array, but omit the first part, and store the second part and third part in your data array of some sort.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a runnable, working solution (with comments explaining some parts):

```
package coordinates;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Path {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        readFromTxt();
    }

    public static void readFromTxt() throws IOException {
        FileReader file = new FileReader("coordinations.txt");
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(file);
        String line = reader.readLine(); // Skip row 0
        List<String> lines = new ArrayList<String>();

        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) { // While there are lines
            lines.add(line);
        }

        int[][] array = new int[lines.size()][2]; // Two dimensional array

        for (int i = 0; i < lines.size(); i++) { // For each line
            String[] l = lines.get(i).split("\t"); // l has length 3
            array[i][0] = Integer.parseInt(l[1]); // 88 (index 1 means second
                                                    // column)
            array[i][1] = Integer.parseInt(l[2]); // 72 (index 2 means third
                                                    // column)
            System.out.println((i + 1) + " (x, y): (" + array[i][0] + ", "
                    + array[i][1] + ")");
        }

        reader.close();
    }
}
```

This removes the top row, ignores the first column, and gives you the 2-D array (`array`).
Note: it is generally not good to use `throws Exception`, as that may prevent you from catching and noticing specific problems with the code. The only necessary exception for this program that you need to throw is `IOException`.

I also changed some method and variable names to fit coding standards for Java.

Answer (score 0):

Change the last bit from

```
for(String textArray:textArrays){
    int coordinates=Integer.parseInt(textArray);// to int 
        System.out.println(coordinates);}}
```

to

```
int x = Integer.parseInt(textArrays[0]);
int y = Integer.parseInt(textArrays[1]);
System.out.println("X Y Coordinates: (%i, %i)", x, y);
```